# Work with date column in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : [1, 2, 2, 1, 3],
                   "status" : ["acc", "rem", "rem", "acc", "other"], "date" : rng})
```

And I need to create DataFrame with columns:

1. New1 = amount of the days from the last "acc" agreemtn until today 28.12
2. New2 = amount of the days from the last "rem" agreement until today 28.12

Result like below:

[image]

Comment: How did values `24` and `25` come? Can you please explain the logic?

Comment: today date is 28.12 so we have 24 days from 04.12 (last acc agreement in ID1) and 25 days from 03.12 (last rem agreement in ID 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [2608]: t = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()

In [2615]: In [2627]: x = abs(df.groupby(['ID', 'status'])['date'].max() - t).dt.days.reset_index()
In [2619]: y = x.pivot('ID', 'status', 'date')

In [2620]: y
Out[2620]: 
status   acc  other   rem
ID                       
1       24.0    NaN   NaN
2        NaN    NaN  25.0
3        NaN   23.0   NaN
```

**Note:** You can rename `acc`, `rem` to `New1` and `New2`. I've kept it as is for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
df=df.groupby(['status'])['date'].agg('last').reset_index()
df['diff']=abs(pd.to_datetime('today').day-df['date'].dt.day)
df_final=df.pivot(columns='status',values='diff')
```

output:

```
df_final
Out[104]: 
status   acc  other   rem
0       24.0    NaN   NaN
1        NaN   23.0   NaN
2        NaN    NaN  25.0
```